# copying data from a webpage to string in cpp using cURL

Tags: php, c++, curl, html

I got a function off of a friend that he found on the net. Problem is, neither of us understand how it works. It copies the contents of the webpage to the string.

We're using cURL to connect to a php page.
The function in question is:

```
std::string contents;

size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
        {
                    int numbytes = size*nmemb;
                    char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1);
                    *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0';
                    contents.append((char *)ptr);
                    contents.append(1,lastchar);
                    *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;  // Might not be necessary.
                    return size*nmemb;
        }
```

Its called in this function:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,handle_data);
```

Any explanations into how this works would be great.
Cheers.

Comment: What part in particular do you not understand?  Have you read this: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is correct:

```
std::string contents;

size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  // The number of bytes to transfer is simply the
  // number of elements (nmemb) times the size of
  // each element (size).
  int numbytes = size*nmemb;

  // Remember the last character of the data we'll
  // be appending to 'contents', because we're about
  // to overwrite it with a zero C-string nul terminator.
  char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1);

  // Overwrite the last character of ptr's data block
  // with zero, which is a C-string's nul-terminator.
  *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0';

  // Append the C-string which begins at 'ptr' to
  // 'contents'.
  contents.append((char *)ptr);

  // Now tack on the last character that we remembered above.
  contents.append(1,lastchar);

  // Restore the original data buffer's last character
  // in case the caller expects it to still be the same.
  *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;  // Might not be necessary.

  // Return the number of bytes  that were appended
  // to 'contents'.
  return size*nmemb;
}
```

Having said all that, I'm not sure why the whole guts of handle_data() isn't simply this:

```
size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    contents.append((char*)ptr, size*nmemb);
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

...which I think would accomplish the exact same thing, only more correctly, since the published version will stop early if the buffer at 'ptr' contains an embedded null character.  (Of course that's probably not a use case for this function anyway.)

Comment: +1. If you hadn't posted it *immediately* after mine, I'd be tempted to wonder if you hadn't copied... :-)

Comment: :)  Yea... I haven't been on SO all that long, but although it's nice for folks asking questions, the large number of answerers (and _good_ answerers) makes it really hard to increase your rep score.  Also having other responsibilities (family, yardwork, etc) puts guys like moi at a disadvantage to single guys like my coworker mmrozek, who has something like 21 gigareps... still short of you, I see.  I'm just waiting for my magic claim-to-fame post like bobince's 4K-upvoted HTML RegEx post, then I could stop worrying about rep.

Comment: When you get one of those posts, you'll quickly find out about the rep cap -- you max out at 200 points a day from up-votes.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's really helpful :)
Just one other thing, what does that (char*) do?
thanks so much

Comment: @user1302398: Please pick your favorite answer & click on the check-mark to the left, selecting it as the best answer.  If you have no preference, I beseech you to pick mine, as I can really use the points and Jerry clearly doesn't need any more! :)

Comment: Oh... missed that last question.  The type of 'ptr' is 'void*', which is not the type of the 1st arg to the version of std::string::append() that we want to use.  Casting a void* to any other non-function-pointer is legal, so we do so to make the compiler realize we want the buffer at 'ptr' to be treated as a buffer of chars, which makes the resulting expression ((void*)ptr) properly typed for the version of std::string::append() that we want to call.

Comment: I guess there's another use of (char*) that's not explained by my earlier comment...  In the statement "*((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0';", the (char*) cast tells the compiler that you want 'ptr' treated as a char pointer, otherwise the compiler has no idea what type to read (char, int, long, float, double), nor how to compute the address of what to read (since the address must be computed by pointer addition, which will be different based on the size of whatever type the pointer is).

Comment: @user1302398: One more thing about the need for the cast in the statement mentioned in my comment above:  One might think the compiler could infer that 'ptr' is a char pointer because you're trying to write a char to it (the '\0' is a char).  But you could just as easily be trying to write the value of a given char into an int variable, and without the cast the compiler doesn't know your intention since 'ptr' is a void*.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to describe how it works, I'd say: "not particularly well".

```
int numbytes = size*nmemb;
```

This computes the size of the buffer -- number of items * size of each item.

```
char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1);
```

This saves the last character in the buffer for later use.

```
*((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0';
```

This adds a NUL terminator to the buffer, overwriting what's currently the last character (which is why the preceding saved it).

```
contents.append((char *)ptr);
```

This appends the (truncated) buffer to the string.

```
contents.append(1,lastchar);
```

This adds the saved last character to the string.

```
*((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;  // Might not be necessary.
```

This restores the last character back into the buffer.

```
return size*nmemb;
```

And this returns the buffer size.

I suppose I should explain why I say this doesn't work very well. It's not that the end result appears to be wrong, but because all the gyration with the final character in the buffer is entirely unnecessary. Instead of NUL terminating the buffer, you can just specify the amount to append to the string:

```
size_t numbytes = size * nmemb;
contents.append((char *)ptr, numbytes);
return numbytes;
```

...or, if you prefer a more iterator-like usage:

```
size_t numbytes = size * nmemb;
char *p = (char *)ptr;
contents.append(p, p+numbytes);
return numbytes;
```

I'm guessing that if you'd found one like these, you wouldn't have had to post a question about how it worked.